# Either Group by or Subquery help not sure will fix the issue

Tags: sql-server, subquery, sql-server-2000

Below is the code I am trying to use however it wants me to add S.Gamingdate to the Group By. When I do that I get a row of results for each player for each day they played. I need just a row for each player summing up all the days. I tried adding a sum around the case statements and moving the sum from the cast to outside the case statements to see if that would help but it did not. I am thinking I will have to subquery but as I am really new to SQL I have not had to subquery before and was hoping for some help.

Using SQL Server 2000

```
Select P.Player_ID
,P.FirstName
,P.LastName
,P.HostUser_ID
,A.HomePhone1
,P.EMail
,A.City1
,M.Miles
,Case when S.GamingDate between '10/1/2014' and '12/31/2014' then Cast(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0) as Decimal (18,2)) Else 0 End) as "3 Month ADT"
,Case when S.GamingDate between '7/1/2014' and '12/31/2014' then Cast(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0) as Decimal (18,2)) Else 0 End) as "6 Month ADT"

From dbo.CDS_ACCOUNT as A
    Join dbo.CDS_Player as P
        on A.Account_ID = P.Player_ID
    Join dbo.CDS_STATDAY as S
        on A.Account_ID = Meta_ID
    Join dbo.Player_Miles as M
        on A.Account_ID = M.Player_ID

Group by P.Player_ID
,P.FirstName
,P.LastName
,P.HostUser_ID
,A.HomePhone1
,P.EMail
,A.City1
,M.Miles
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your expressions for [3 Month ADT] and [6 Month ADT] to have S.GamingDate inside the SUM. Without a schema I can't test this but something like this should do the trick;

```
Cast(Sum(Case when S.GamingDate between '10/1/2014' and '12/31/2014' then S.TWin else null end)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0) as Decimal (18,2))) as "3 Month ADT"
```

Also, you might need to remove the NULLIF - if it ever returns 0 you would get a division-by-zero error.

**Edit to provide more info and a complete working script;**

I've created a complete script that anyone can run in an empty database. Firstly, after un-picking the expressions for [3 Month ADT] and [6 Month ADT] I think what you are trying to do is get the average TWin over dates played? In which case just use the AVG function - it will ignore NULLs (dates not played). Note the 1.0 * in front of S.TWin - if your TWin is an integer this will convert it to a decimal so that the result of the AVG is decimal too. Also note the LEFT JOIN to dbo.CDS_STATDAY - this prevents players without an entry in dbo.CDS_STATDAY from disappearing from the results.

If I've not quite grasped what you're trying to do let me know.

```
/*
-- Schema script to create some dummy tables and data

create table dbo.CDS_ACCOUNT (
    Account_ID int,
    HomePhone1 varchar(20),
    City1 varchar(20)
)
create table dbo.CDS_Player (
    Player_ID int,
    FirstName varchar(20),
    LastName varchar(20),
    HostUser_ID int,
    EMail  varchar(20)
)
create table dbo.CDS_STATDAY (
    Meta_ID int,
    GamingDate date,
    TWin int
)
create table dbo.Player_Miles (
    Player_ID int,
    Miles int
)
go

set nocount on
insert dbo.CDS_ACCOUNT values (1,'Phone1','City1')
insert dbo.CDS_ACCOUNT values (2,'Phone2','City2')
insert dbo.CDS_ACCOUNT values (3,'Phone3','City3')
insert dbo.CDS_ACCOUNT values (4,'Phone4','City4')

insert dbo.CDS_Player values (1, 'Tom','Alas',101,'Email1')
insert dbo.CDS_Player values (2, 'Dick','Smith',102,'Email2')
insert dbo.CDS_Player values (3, 'Harry','Jones',103,'Email3')
insert dbo.CDS_Player values (4, 'Han','Solo',104,'Email4')

insert dbo.CDS_STATDAY values (1,'2014-01-01',10)
insert dbo.CDS_STATDAY values (1,'2014-11-01',10)
insert dbo.CDS_STATDAY values (2,'2014-01-01',9)
insert dbo.CDS_STATDAY values (2,'2014-09-01',9)
insert dbo.CDS_STATDAY values (2,'2014-11-01',10)
insert dbo.CDS_STATDAY values (3,'2014-01-01',9)
insert dbo.CDS_STATDAY values (3,'2014-07-01',9)
insert dbo.CDS_STATDAY values (3,'2014-09-01',10)
insert dbo.CDS_STATDAY values (3,'2014-11-01',11)

insert dbo.Player_Miles values (1, 50)
insert dbo.Player_Miles values (2, 60)
insert dbo.Player_Miles values (3, 70)
insert dbo.Player_Miles values (4, 80)
go
*/

Select P.Player_ID
,P.FirstName
,P.LastName
,P.HostUser_ID
,A.HomePhone1
,P.EMail
,A.City1
,M.Miles
,avg(Case when S.GamingDate between '10/1/2014' and '12/31/2014' then 1.0 * S.TWin else null end) as "3 Month ADT"
,avg(Case when S.GamingDate between '7/1/2014' and '12/31/2014' then 1.0 * S.TWin else null end) as "6 Month ADT"

From dbo.CDS_ACCOUNT as A
    Join dbo.CDS_Player as P
        on A.Account_ID = P.Player_ID
    Left Join dbo.CDS_STATDAY as S
        on A.Account_ID = Meta_ID
    Join dbo.Player_Miles as M
        on A.Account_ID = M.Player_ID

Group by P.Player_ID
,P.FirstName
,P.LastName
,P.HostUser_ID
,A.HomePhone1
,P.EMail
,A.City1
,M.Miles
```

Hope this helps.

Rhys

Comment: Was going to suggest the same.  But you probably also need to do another CASE on the other side of the division as well.   Otherwise you'll divide by the count of all records, and not just those in the date range.

Comment: The idea of moving the case inside the sum is brilliant thanks. However it appears @TabAlleman is right it dividing by all days not just those in the range. Also my understanding is that the nullif is there to prevent the divide by zero error as if the count of distinct S.GamingDate is 0 it returns a Null instead of 0.

Comment: I tried adding the Extra case statement and got the error about adding S.GamingDate to the Group by again. Here is what I tried. ,Cast(Sum(Case when S.GamingDate between '10/1/2014' and '12/31/2014' then S.TWin else null end)/Case when S.GamingDate between '10/1/2014' and '12/31/2014' then Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0)else null end as Decimal (18,2)) as "3 Month ADT"

Comment: If someone could edit that to make that a code and teach me how that would be great I can never get the code to work in comments

Comment: Maybe this will code it right `,Cast(Sum(Case when S.GamingDate between '10/1/2014' and '12/31/2014' then S.TWin else null end)/Case when S.GamingDate between '10/1/2014' and '12/31/2014' then Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0)else null end as Decimal (18,2)) as "3 Month ADT"`

Comment: Still not the nice style I have in my first post or what @RhysJones has in his but not sure how to do that.

Comment: @ChadPortman, I think your suggestion should work, but I would put the Nullif() outside the case statement so it operates over the whole denominator.   Like .../nullif(case...then count(...) else null end)

Comment: I updated it to `,Cast(Sum(Case when S.GamingDate between '10/1/2014' and '12/31/2014' then S.TWin else null end)/Nullif(Case when S.GamingDate between '10/1/2014' and '12/31/2014' then Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0)else null end as Decimal (18,2)) as "3 Month ADT"` but I now get an error stating Incorrect Syntax near ',' for this line.

Comment: Also I meant to ask @RhysJones when you said without a schema you can not test is that something I could have provided? I am not sure what that is.

Comment: @ChadPortman - the schema info (tables, data etc) is just to make it easier for people to run your query - if you give people a complete script that they can run to help you you'll get a better answer quicker. I'll update my answer with a complete script, and some more info.

Comment: @RhysJones Thank you so much for the info about the schema I will remember that in the future and work on adding that to my questions on here in the future. The Left Join is new for me I like how that works. Good info to know. The only weird thing is using the new Avg style you posted the numbers do not come out rounded to only 2 decimal places which I need cause this is actually money. You were right in what the goal was though.

Comment: @ChadPortman - sorry, I missed this last comment. If you haven't already got what you want then add a CAST around the AVG, i.e. `cast(round(AVG(...), 2) as decimal(18,2)`.